# Can I do a Tiger Shoot like Hyuga Kojiro from anime Captain Tsubasa

Tags: captain-tsubasa

What if I train myself during a storm on the beach and kick the ball as hard as I can. Can I master tiger shoot and the ball shines?

Comment: Not familiar with the anime/manga but I looked up this particular move in the Internet. Based on the way the move was 'invented', I think this question might possibly lead to opinion-based answers.

Comment: This question might not be for this SE. Not sure, may be sports. I've seen the anime, and I played soccer thousands of times, no you can't. What they do in captain tsubasa is mostly fantasy

Comment: As the question currently stands, it is unclear what you are asking, because we do not know which version of the Tiger Shoot you mean. Do you mean the one from the original manga, the first anime, the Super Famicom game, the Playstation 2 game, the present animated series or something else? Also, by shine, do you mean like a glint or a fiery aura? However, I opine the question is otherwise on-topic. It is anime related, and it is possible to corroborate this answer using facts and references. [Concretely, people have tried to recreate at least some of the shots.](https://youtu.be/V2LzbxRzkdAt)

Comment: I also would very much advice that you do not go out during a large scale typhoon. This would be a significant health hazard.

Comment: Do you mean to shoot a ball exactly like the animation of Tiger Shoot or just the power and speed?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not within the scope of anime or manga as defined in this meta post: https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/668/is-it-ever-acceptable-to-ask-about-whether-an-anime-event-is-realistic-or-plausi

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't set a ball on fire or encrust the ball in a wall like Kojiro does with the Tiger shoot. No man has the strenght to do it and if they would the ball would break apart first.